# Java. Save File to Client side not working

Tags: java, file-io

I want to save File to a client side. How it can be done ? 
When i start server localy all is good Files are saved @ needed place, when run on server then files are saved on server side :( . Because System.getProperty("user.home") are returning :/root . 
User select File from system and wants to open it. Code example:

```
mylog.pl("Blob in use + stop counter:" + stop);
File file = new File(SU.userHome + "/" + fileName);
mylog.pl("File maked ! Path:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
in = blob.getBinaryStream();
out = new FileOutputStream(file);
byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
int len = 0;
while ((len = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
      out.write(buff, 0, len);
 }                              
try {
      mylog.pl("Desktop Open!");
      if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
       {
         Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
       } 
      else 
      {
        mylog.pl("Desktop is not suported!");
        //For other IS
        DesktopApi.open(file);
      }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
         mylog.pl("err @ runtime" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Thanks ! Correct answers guaranteed !

Comment: Is this a web application? or are you running your application from a server ?

Comment: You can serve the document in a JSP (not recommended) or the BEST aproch is to create yourself a servlet and serve the content in the HTTP Response , Take a look at this post http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=232

Answer (score 0):

```
                            //From server to client
                            final FileResource res = new FileResource(file);
                            FileDownloader fd = new FileDownloader(res);
                            p.open(res, "MyWindow", false);
                            file.delete();
```